# java awt per pixel renderer porting to imgui

Tags: java, awt, lwjgl, imgui

I've recently been working on a java awt application, it started out as a very simple render testing demo but has sort of cascaded and so to make my life easier I have decided to switch to imgui (with an lwjgl backend). I have never used lwjgl but I have used imgui with c++.

In it's current format the gui of the application is incredibly simplistic as I tweak most variables for the algorithms i'm demoing with it from within code which is precisely why I want to start switching over to imgui.
Currently it mostly consists of a pair of images, one which is a per pixel visualisation of my 2d algorithms and one which uses awts graphics features to draw some rectangles to represent other data. essentially producing 2 dynamic images every frame.

my question is then, how would I do this per pixel rendering (and possibly some of the rectangle drawing) inside of lwjgl and get these displaying as part of an imgui gui.
that or getting imgui and my existing awt renderer to coexist within the same window.

EDIT:
Thought I'd add a summary here:
Littereally all I wanna know is how I can get ImGui to render an image that I can modify from within java every frame with some sort of SetPixelAt function.

Comment: For per pixel rendering I would recommend using a BufferedImage.

Comment: as in the awt class? do you have any idea how I would get this into imgui's image function?

Comment: I was just reading about lwjql - it looks like what I suggested won't work. Furthermore, it looks like there is no way to do this ( from what I read) (http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=4762.0)

Comment: I mean there must be some kind of way to have cpu dynamic textures with imgui, I don't necessarily need to use AWT, that just happens to be what I've used so far.